# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url giving 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

While debugging in Visual Studio which is running at following URL `http://localhost:39452/` 
I am getting `http://127.0.0.1` as the value for following property

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

instead of `http://localhost:39452/` 
I am having this value in my hosts file:

```
::1  localhost
```

Can you let me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `localhost` _is_ `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Also, 39452 is the port that the server is listening on, not the port that the client is using. `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` never includes the port number, so you're getting the correct value.

Comment: @itsme86, I'd assume that URL should contain port number as well.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you are trying to get the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` value too early.

For example; during the `Init` event of a `HttpModule` you may face with these kind of problems. I mean you may get `http://127.0.0.1/myApp` instead of the correct value of `http://localhost/myApp`.

Answer (score 4):

Both are localhost; `::1` is the shorthand notation of the IPv6 version and `127.0.0.1` is the IPv4 version.

I guess your assumption that you are doing something wrong, is the only thing you're doing wrong! :)

Comment: Yep, but default port for HTTP is 80, not 39452, thus URI should contain the port number as well.